# Is an M.2 Wi-Fi card backwards compatible with regular PCIe?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, pci-express

So I have this HP laptop from 2014 which has a Realtek RTL8188EE 802.11bgn Wi-Fi card. There have been issues with it. I know it's a PCIe Wi-Fi card. I've been looking for replacements, like the Intel Dual-Band AC 9560. The only confusion I have is that the Intel card is M.2 PCIe whereas the Realtek card isn't M.2. I'm also aware that M.2 can use the PCIe lanes. My question is whether or not the Intel M.2 PCIe Wi-Fi card will work on a presumably non-M.2 PCIe slot. Any clarification would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: They are physically different but electrically the same. Assuming you have the physical room for it, there's 'simple' mini PCIe to m.2 adaptors that should work. That said, you probably will not. I suspect the 'easy/cheap' option is just to stick in a USB wifi dongle

Comment: Today, when you buy a PCIe Wi-Fi card, that's exactly what you get: A M.2 card mounted in an adapter with external antenna connectors (those are super important). // If the card supports Bluetooth, it will require a USB connection, too.

Answer (score 0):

PCIe is an *interface specification*, which defines electrical specs and logical specs and allows for different physical form factors. Consequently, the hardware which uses PCI express interface comes in different form factors. In particular, [M.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2#Form_factors_and_keying) "type B" card *can* provide up to 2 PCIe lanes, while "type M" can provide up to 4.

But not that M.2 connectors also provide other logical interfaces than PCIe, for instance, common ones are SATA (which is used for M.2 SATA SSDs) and USB.

Depending on what exactly interface the particular M.2 card uses, it is possible to use a *passive* adapter (that comes without any electronics, just wires and physical locks to secure the card) to connect it into "standard" socket: PCIe, SATA, USB and so on and communicate with the card, but in each case that would be different adapter. (In some cases it is possible to have an adapter that makes several interfaces accessible simultaneously, e.g. USB and PCIe.)

In particular, NVMe interface is PCIe, so you can use the same passive adaptors that are used to connect M.2 NVMe SSDs into standard PCIe slot for any PCIe cards. But if SSD happens to be not NVMe (e.g. it is SATA), such adapter won't make it accessible in PCIe slot, likewise this adapter won't help if your card uses USB. In those cases you need to use other adapters.

If you have the right adapter for the card, e.g. M.2-to-PCIe and the card is really M.2 PCIe, *it is perfectly compartible*! Notice that wireless cards usually have antenna connectors, and you will need to lay antenna wires outside of the metal case somehow, else it will be recognized in the system, but will struggle to connect to any wireless network being enclosed into Faraday's cage.

Conversely, it is possible to create a "reverse" adapter  that allows plugging a "standard" PCIe card into M.2 socket that has PCIe lanes wired; this could be used to connect a discrete PCIe video card to a laptop by sacrificing the wireless connectivity and using the socket that is usually occupied by the WiFi card.